# Determining default gateway with Tcl

Tags: network-programming, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tcl/Tk script, and I need to find the default gateway of the computer it's running on to establish a connection to the router. Is there any way (preferably cross-platform) to find out what the computer's default gateway is set to?

I imagine that for Linux (Ubuntu, specifically -- the platform I'm targeting) I could call the "route" command and parse that, but I'm not sure that would work on Windows, and I'd like to avoid making system calls if possible, on principle.

Answer (score 3):

The way to get information about the network routing *is* to ask the OS. This is also an operation that isn't very cross-platform. On Windows, the simplest way to do this is to parse the output of `ipconfig /all`.

```
set output [exec {*}[auto_execok ipconfig] /all]
if {[regexp -line {Default Gateway[ .]*: (.+)} $output -> gw]} {
    puts "The default gateway is $gw"
} else {
    puts "No default gateway found"
}
```

On Linux, you need to do this:

```
# Note, might not be on your PATH by default
set output [exec /sbin/route -n]
if {[regexp -line {^0\.0\.0\.0\s+([0-9.]+)} $output -> gw]} {
    puts "The default gateway is $gw"
} else {
    puts "No default gateway found"
}
```

On OSX (and other BSD derivatives), you need a different incantation:

```
set output [exec /sbin/route -n get 0.0.0.0]
if {[regexp -line {gateway: ([0-9.]+)} $output -> gw]} {
    puts "The default gateway is $gw"
} else {
    puts "No default gateway found"
}
```

As you can see, this is frustratingly difficult! Let's wrap it up in a procedure that uses [`tcl_platform`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M24) to decide what to do.

```
proc gateway {varName} {
    upvar 1 $varName gw
    global tcl_platform
    if {$tcl_platform(platform) eq "windows"} {
        set output [exec {*}[auto_execok ipconfig] /all]
        set RE {Default Gateway[ .]*: (.+)}
    } elseif {$tcl_platform(os) eq "Linux"} {
        set output [exec /sbin/route -n]
        set RE {^0\.0\.0\.0\s+([0-9.]+)}
    } else {
        # Assume we're OSX or BSD
        set output [exec /sbin/route -n get 0.0.0.0]
        set RE {gateway: ([0-9.]+)}
    }
    return [regexp -line $RE $output -> gw]
}
```

Now you'll be able to do this on all platforms:

```
if {[gateway gw]} {
    puts "The default gateway is $gw"
} else {
    puts "No default gateway found"
}
```

The underlying code isn't portable, but your code can be. Easy!

Comment: Fairly elegant answer; I like. Upvoting for now, will wait to see if anyone else comes along with something mindblowing before I immediately accept  (my one complaint is that it does make system/exec calls, which I'm not fond of) :)